# Один из сайтов на сервере CentOS вешает mysql

Tags: centos, mysql

Такая проблема.Один из сайтов на сервере вешает mysql. Целиком.Иногда даже перезагрузка только базы не помогает.Приходится в перезапуск весь сервер отправлять.

Данные сервера:ОС - CentOS-6-amd64MySQL - Версия сервера: 5.1.66phpMyAdmin - 2.11.11.3, версия MySQL-клиента: 5.1.66

Перед зависанием в ISP-manager в разделе "Нагрузка http-сервера"этот сайт показывает до 200 000 ошибок.У остальных до 1 000.

Не представляю даже, что делать и как к этому подступиться.Мало того, не могу найти как включить логи ошибок базы.

Comment: Наверное, стоит задать вопрос тому, кто разрабатывал сайт... Не?

Comment: ну если     Иногда даже перезагрузка только базы не помогает. это же не проблема базы уже, что там htop говорит, когда база опущена?

Answer (score 1):

Включи все возможные логи (временно) и лови запрос на котором виснет. От этого и пляши.Лучше всего, конечно, делать это на тестовом стенде (в виртуалке, например). Заодно рассмотри (и проверь) обновление мускула или переход на МариюДБ.

http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/22772/http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=drk.xbnm%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%20mysql&clid=1923022&lr=213